# Airflow Dags failing with Error: Options kube_config_path, kube_config, in_cluster are mutually exclusive. You can only use one option at a time

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I am running a local deployment of airflow on Kubernetes and using git-sync to pull my dags. When I run my dags, they fail with the message:

`Creating pod load-weather-data-63b8f20d51e14ae4b0838c2e1c43c259 with labels: {'dag_id': 'hello-generic-world-0802134835', 'task_id': 'Load_weather_data', 'run_id': 'kubernetes_pod_operator': 'True', 'try_number': '1'}`

`Deleting pod: load-weather-data-63b8f20d51e14ae4b0838c2e1c43c259`

`ERROR - Invalid connection configuration. Options kube_config_path, kube_config, in_cluster are mutually exclusive. You can only use one option at a time.`

I have deleted previous configurations and when I run `kubectl config view`, I only see the config for the cluster in use.

From what I have read online, the error has to do with this line in my dag:

```
in_cluster = true,
config_file="None"
```

When running airflow on Kubernetes locally and with **in_cluster** set to **true,** do I need to create a config that tells airflow how to connect to the cluster? If yes, how do I do that?

Note: When I run `kubectl config view` this is what the configuration looks like:

````
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://127.0.0.1:57838
  name: kind-airflow-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kind-airflow-cluster
    user: kind-airflow-cluster
  name: kind-airflow-cluster
current-context: kind-airflow-cluster
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kind-airflow-cluster
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED```
````

Comment: based solely upon that snippet provided without one shred of context, I'd guess it is interpreting `config_file="None"` as the **path** `./None` and even though there is no such file, it is whining about `in_cluster = True` *and* a truthy `config_file` value. Perhaps you meant `config_file = None` instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running airflow in a pod, you don't need kube config file, activating `in_cluster` option and creating a service account and a role with the verbs verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "delete"] on the resource pods, and adding this service account to the pod where you serve airflow are enough to use the kubernetes hook and operators

For airflow configurations, you can keep the default config in airflow.cfg:

```
[kubernetes]
in_cluster = True,
# config_file =
```